# Is there a way to dynamically render a react component with a variable width?

Tags: javascript, html, jsx, scheduler, job-scheduling

I am working on a First Come First Serve CPU scheduler with JavaScript. The problem I am facing is that for some reason my component for the gantt-chart visualization does not render when it is supposed to (When the calculations are completed). The component however does render when I make a change to the code and the calculations have completed.

It seems as though the rendering is at random as sometimes when I add in a console.log(processes) to see what is happening right before I map the data to a process, 1) the data is there and 2) It randomly will render.

Code for Gantt-Chart component:

```
export default function GanttChart({processes}) {
  return (
    <div className="chart-area">
        <div className="gantt-chart">
            {processes.map((process) => (
                <> 
                    <div key={process.processName} className="process" style={{ width: (parseInt(process.burstTime, 10)) + "%" }}>{process.processName}</div>
                </>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm trying to have this component to render after  calcTurnAroundWaitingTime() function executes and the width of each "process" is based upon the burstTime of that process:

Function that handles the FirstComeFirstServe Algorithm:

```
function handleFCFS(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // Pushing the process data from the form to the process array for each process
        processData.forEach(process => {
            processes.push(process);
        });

        // Error checking if there are no processes to process by seeing if the first processName === null
        if (!processes[0].processName){
            alert("Nothing to process");
            return;
        }

        processes.join(); // Joining the array of objects together as a string separated by ,
        processes.sort(orderLeastGreatest); // Sorting the string by calling the compare  function that compares the objects arrival times

        // Calculating completion time
        calcCompletionTime(processes);

        // Calculating turnaround time and waiting time
        calcTurnAroundWaitingTime(processes);
```

Comment: The only way to cause a render in react is by setting state. It doesn't look like you're ever doing that in this code. Some other component is probably setting state for unrelated reasons, which is causing the "random" renders.

Comment: You're missing the key property, that might confuse React in unexpected ways.. Just remove that `<> </>` or replace it with `<React.fragment key={process....`

Comment: can you show screen shot of browser as well ?